# How to name RESTful endpoint that's described using two identifiers?

Tags: rest

When resource has a unique identifier it is retrieved:

`/building/{building_id}`

But what if "event" resource is described using `building_id` and `floor_id` parameters. How to name RESTful endpoint that is meant to retrieve present events?

To be precise, "event" resource has a unique identifier (`id`). Combination of `building_id`, `floor_id` ought to return present event in a particular location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But what if "event" resource is described using building_id and floor_id parameters.

Is it? I recommend this:

If

```
GET /events/{id}
```

returns one event and

```
GET /events
```

returns all events, then

```
GET /events?building_id={building_id}&floor_id={floor_id}
```

returns the list of (possibly only one) event(s) at the combination of `building_id` and `floor_id`.

This looks like the often used filter-or-search-a-collection-resource-pattern.

Comment: Adding query params,if possible, is the best solution.+1

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the solution by Lutz, in case if you dont want them to be `query parameters`. 
Assuming, from the name as it looks, floor_id is part of building_id , so if the event  resource is defined as combination of both , it can be like

```
/event/{event_id}/building/{building_id}/floor/{floor_Id}
```

Comment: This could be used if the number of possible parameter combinations is small. It will become difficult to use if the number of parameters is larger or they are optional.

Comment: Right, Lutz, adding in query param is the best option, I suggested this only when we dont want query params

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by trying to think what resource owns what. Obviously, buildings own floors (knock the building down, the floor is destroyed!) so that's a relationship that maps nicely to a sub-resource, but do events own buildings or do buildings/floors own events? No? Then we relate these by links. (A floor *might* have a current event concept as something it owns, but that's really a link to an event, not an event *per se*.)

```
/building/{building_id}
/building/{building_id}/floor/{floor_id}
/building/{building_id}/floor/{floor_id}/current-event --redirect--> some event
/event/{event_id}
```

The event probably should have hyperlinks to the building and floor which it involves. Going the other way, if there's no current event for a floor, fetching the `…/current-event` will result in a 404, and if there *is* an event, a 303 redirect will say which it is. (You might also want to make the record for the floor itself contain a true link to the event, as well as a convenience lookup sub-resource.)

A good RESTful application looks an awful lot like a densely linked website. Use the power of links and redirects!

Comment: Does not effect the message that you are trying to deliver, but in my example "floor" does not refer to a physical building floor, but rather to elevation level. `/building/{id}/floor/{id}` would be ambiguous. Therefore, I have chosen to go with Lutz suggestion.